# Merge multiple rows in table vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

[image]

I am trying to create a table which merges some rows but also merges some rows vertically (with vertical text).

My code so far looks like this

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c| }
\toprule
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{}}&  & \textit{\textbf{a}} & \textit{\textbf{b}} & \textit{\textbf{c}}   \\

\cmidrule{2-5}
\multirow{7}{*}[-0.4ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{merged over 3}}} 
& \textit{\textbf{These two should be merged}}   &  &  &    \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{These two should be merged}}  &  & &     \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{}}  &  &  &     \\
\cmidrule{2-5}

& \textit{\textbf{1}} &  &  &    \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{2}}  &  &  &      \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{3}}  &  &  &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like the following? Please note that you shouldn't use vertical lines together with the rules provided by `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{}}&  & \textit{\textbf{a}} & \textit{\textbf{b}} & \textit{\textbf{c}}   \\

\cmidrule{2-5}
\multirow{7}{*}[-0.4ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{merged over 3}}} 
&    &  &  &    \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
  &
  \multirow{-2}{*}[\dimexpr\cmidrulesep+.5\cmidrulewidth\relax]{\textit{\textbf{These two should be merged}}}  &  & &     \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{}}  &  &  &     \\
\cmidrule{2-5}

& \textit{\textbf{1}} &  &  &    \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{2}}  &  &  &      \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \textit{\textbf{3}}  &  &  &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I would also like the "merged over 3" to be only splut over the first three lines and then for another box to be vertically merged over the bottom three lines. I require the table to have vertical lines  also. Should I therefore be using another package ? thanks

Comment: sorry just to clarify the first colum should two vertical boxes each split over three rows.

Comment: @Bat you can only rotate the contents of the first column if your contents are small enough to fit into them, `\multirow` doesn't vertically enlarge the rows it's used on. If you need vertical lines you could either reduce the vertical separation around the rules provided by `booktabs`, or just use LaTeX's `\hline` and `\cline` macros instead. I think you can use two `\multirow` instances on the first column yourself, after all there are already two usage examples contained in my answer.

Comment: ah ok perfect thanks for clarfying that for me ! I will give the table another try with your suggestions. Many thanks for your help